# Add dynamically created element to the scope of Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular JS, and am struggling with a very naive problem.

I have a directive that gives blue background to DOM elements when added in a class *xyz*.

I also have a third party jQuery library that adds new elements with the *xyz* class.
The problem is that the new elements created by the jQuery library do not get the blue background.

```
var test = angular.module("Test", []);
test.directive("awesome", function () {
   return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).css("background", "blue");
        }
    }
});


function Ctrl($scope, $http, $timeout) {

}

//Third party jQuery plugin will add a span with the class "awesome"
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".append").append('<span class="awesome">Success</span>');
});
```

jsFiddle link attached. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sfDtX/1/)

Comment: It is because the angular framework is unaware about the dynamically added elements

Comment: Yep! I get that! But how to make it aware? I believe that $compile is what I need to use, but I don't know how!

Comment: At first look, there is a design problem here because since you are using angular js you should not be doing any dom manipulation directly (ie other than inside a directive) so probably you need to check why you want to do it in the first place

Comment: The problem above is just a simplification. I am dependent on a jQuery plugin for a much bigger task. So ditching direct DOM manipulation is not really an option.

Comment: I had the same question, found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073721/why-is-angular-js-not-smart-enough-to-compile-dom-when-adding-dynamic-elements

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using jQuery outside of angular. However, AngularJS has a wrapper: `angular.element('jquery selector here');` and the `element` parameter of linking function is already a jquery [lite] element, the one that matched the directive.

Firstly, having a directive to assign a color is overkilling. If this is not a simplified example, you might want to reconsider it.
Secondly, you're on the right track. You need to use the `$compile` service to make angular aware of the new directives.

In the linking function of `awesome` you add an element to the DOM. You know that it will trigger a directive, angular doesn't. You compile it, now angular knows. [See the example live](http://jsfiddle.net/sfDtX/2/)

Your `awesome` directive stays as is:

```
test.directive("awesome", function () {
return {
    replace: false,
    restrict: 'C',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.css("background", "blue");
    }
}
});
```

Now if any other directive appends elements that  can trigger new directives, you compile them, as follows:

```
test.directive("whatever", function ($compile) {
return {
    replace: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.append('<span class="awesome">Awesome</span>'); 
        $compile(element.contents())(scope); // compile ONLY the contents or you'll enjoy an infinite loop in the browser.
    }
}
});
```

You'll probably have to write a wrapper for the jquery library that you mention. There are some resources on-line about integrating jquery plugins with angularjs. the angular-bootstrap project is an example

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I am looking for a solution where I do not need to make any changes/ write a wrapper for the jQuery library. And yes, indeed this is a simplification. Should'nt there be a way such that we can let Angular know about the newly created element?

Comment: I was facing similar kind of problem and finally I found the solution from my own and created a Plnckr ..Hope this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lkfirfr0Qo3HoviYru29?p=preview) would help you..